# Comparing a List to a matrix to get the value in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an MS Excel matrix with Width on the rows and Height on the columns.
The value where the intersection is, is a code.

This matrix always remains the same.

I also have a list where I have 3 columns: A=Width B=Height C=Cell that needs to be populated by the code in the cell with the specified width and height.

How would I do this in Excel?

[image: Example]

[image: Matrix]

## NOTE: The numbers in the Example have been rounded UP to match the matrix.

Comment: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a lookup table of codes indexed by width and height.  If I understand your question correctly, this is easily done with the OFFSET() function using two MATCH() functions as the indexes.

Here is a representation of your lookup table starting in Column E, and the results of the lookup in Column C:

[image]

The formula in C2, and filled down, is:

`=OFFSET($E$2,MATCH(A2,$E$3:$E$18,0),MATCH(B2,$F$2:$U$2,0))`

This finds the position of width A2 in the list of widths in Column E, and the position of height B2 in the list of heights in Row 2, and gets the code that is offset that number of rows and columns from E2.

PS: After seeing your pictures, it looks like I have width and height switched, but you get the idea.

Comment: Great, THANK YOU.  Let me try this right now.

Comment: Okay so i have done it, and flipped the two selections around to match mine.  However it shows '#N/A'.  What does the $E$2 do in '=OFFSET($E$2'.  Mine looks like this: =OFFSET($M$3,MATCH(C3,$N$3:$AJ$3,0),MATCH(D3,$M$4:$M$19,0))

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZfUP.jpg

Comment: $E$2 is the "start position" for the OFFSET().  Looking at the formula in C3, the first MATCH() says go down 4 rows from E2 (because 8 is the 4th item in the list) and the second match says go over 11 columns (because 15 is the 11th item in the list).

Comment: You're getting #N/A because 2030 and 1600 are not in the lists.  The zero tells MATCH() to find an *exact* match.  If you change the Match type to 1, it will get the highest value that it finds that is lower than what it was looking for, and -1 will return the lowest value that is higher than what it was looking for.

Comment: Just read your edit, sorry to take so long.  Since you want to round up, use -1.

Comment: You've been great so far.  So i have got it partially working.  It rounds down perfectly, but when i try to round up or do exact, it gives me the #N/A.

Comment: I've done that.  That works, but it is still one out.  I have started the reference at the first vertex which seems to get the right answer.  Is this correct? - Either way i will use it for now.  Thanks again

Comment: The only way I could get the -1 type to work was to rearrange the lookup table so width and height are in descending order.